# Write multimap fo file Fast way c++

Tags: c++, file

I am using the following code to cound the frequency of words :
// Program for Owen written by Briana Morrison

```
//#pragma warning (disable : 4786)
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

// program assumes that the filename is the only thing passed into program
// if you are using standard argc and argv, then arguments to main should change, and uncomment 
//   first line.
int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    string filename(argv[1]);
  //  string filename;

    //cout << "Enter filename" << endl;
    //cin >> filename;

    ifstream infile(filename.c_str());
    //ifstream infile("poe.txt");

    string word;
    bool debug = false; // for debugging purposes
    int count = 0;      // count of words for debugging

    // create a map of words to frequencies
    map<string, int, less<string> > words;
    // create a multimap of frequencies to words
    multimap<int, string, greater<int> > freq;

    // loop while there is input in the file  
    infile >> word; //priming read
    while (infile)
    {
       count++;
       // convert word to lowercase
       for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++)
           if ('A' <= word[i] && word[i] <= 'Z')
              word[i] = tolower(word[i]);

        if (debug) cout << word << endl;
        // if word not found, add to map, otherwise increment count
        if (words.find(word) != words.end())
        {
            words[word]++;
            if (debug) cout << word << " found and count incremented to " << words[word] << endl;
        }
        else
        {
            words[word] = 1;
            if (debug) cout << word << " not found and count incremented to " << words[word] << endl;
        }

        infile >> word;
    }

    if (debug) cout << "count is " << count << " and map has " << words.size() << endl;

    // now go through map and add everything to multimap...words still in alphabetical order
    map<string, int, less<string> >::iterator it = words.begin();
    for (it = words.begin(); it != words.end(); it++)
    {
        pair<int, string> p(it->second, it->first);
        freq.insert(p);
    }

    if (debug) cout << "map has " << words.size() << " and multimap has " << freq.size() << endl;

    ofstream outfile("myout.txt");

    multimap<int, string, greater<int> >::iterator myit=freq.begin();
    for (myit = freq.begin(); myit != freq.end(); myit++)
    {
        outfile << myit->first << "\t" << myit->second << endl;
    }
    outfile.close();

  return 0;
}
```

---

The problem is not in here I think

When i am writing the words to a file, it gets slower by every iteration why?

```
        ofstream outfile("myout.txt");

        multimap<int, string, greater<int> >::iterator myit=freq.begin();
        for (myit = freq.begin(); myit != freq.end(); myit++)
        {
            outfil<< myit->first << "\t" << myit->second << endl;
        }
       outfile.close();
```

How can I write the multimap in a fast way to a file?

Comment: How do you know that it gets slower by every iteration? I suspect that you're judging it wrong.

Comment: Actually I think I am. I don't think writing to a file is not the one that is slowing the code. You are right @MM.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `'\n'` instead of [`std::endl`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/endl) to avoid flushing it for every line.

```
outfil << myit->first << '\t' << myit->second << '\n';
```

Comment: Well I just changed endl with "\n" and still the same, it's still slow hmmm

Comment: My File is now **11** MB, with **533** lines and it's getting slower

Comment: @HaniGoc: In your code you're writing the output in `cout` not `outfil` recheck your code again.

Comment: @HaniGoc: OK, for now. Is changing `endl` to `\n` effective?

Answer (score 3):

```
for (myit = freq.begin(); myit != freq.end(); ++myit)
{
    outfil<< myit->first << "\t" << myit->second << "\n";
}
```

this should be faster.

Or you can buffer the data and write them all at once, not line by line.

Comment: The problem is that the data that i want to write to a file are around **600 MB**

Answer (score 1):

I don't see why your loop should get slower with every single iteration, but note that you're using *formatted output* (which is what `operator<<` does), which is notoriously slow. In case your strings don't contain null bytes you could make your code more efficient by writing the `std::string` via [`ostream::write`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ostream/ostream/write/) i.e.

```
outfil << myit->first;
outfil.write( "\t", 1 );
outfil.write( myit->second.c_str(), myit->second.size() );
outfil.write( "\n", 1 );
```

Comment: I am having an error :
error: no matching function for call to 'std::basic_ofstream<char>::write(std::basic_string<char>&, std::basic_string<char>::size_type)'|

Comment: @HaniGoc Had a small mistake in my code example (you should have `myit->second.c_str()`, i.e. pass a `const char*`, when calling `write()`).

Comment: I think that i should use string buffer, it's also way too slow. I'll look in this way better @Frerich Raabe